# What's the meaning of ''bore'' in the sentence?

Tags: word-meaning

> "Platitude in bad Greek written by a Roman **bore**," the priest growled.

What's the meaning of "bore" in the sentence?

Answer (score 2):

[Merriam Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/bore):

> a dull or tiresome person
> *His friends are a bunch of bores.*